# 2 dimensional array in C# like in other languages

Tags: c#, arrays

I have data like this:

```
44 {5,8,0,0,2,5,9}
99 {9,9,9,9,5,5,1}
12 {0,0,9,5,1,7,1}
```

The first number is like a primary key and other numbers in brackets are its values.

I would like to save the data above into arrays like this:

```
int id = 0;
int ids[];
int data[][7];

ids[id] = 44;
data[ids[id]][0] = 5;
data[ids[id]][1] = 8;
data[ids[id]][2] = 0;
data[ids[id]][3] = 0;
data[ids[id]][4] = 2;
data[ids[id]][5] = 5;
data[ids[id]][6] = 9;
id++;
ids[id] = 99;
data[ids[id]][0] = 9;
data[ids[id]][1] = 9;
data[ids[id]][2] = 9;
data[ids[id]][3] = 9;
data[ids[id]][4] = 5;
data[ids[id]][5] = 5;
data[ids[id]][6] = 1;
id++;
ids[id] = 12;
data[ids[id]][0] = 0;
data[ids[id]][1] = 0;
data[ids[id]][2] = 9;
data[ids[id]][3] = 5;
data[ids[id]][4] = 1;
data[ids[id]][5] = 7;
data[ids[id]][6] = 1;
id++;
```

And then acces them like this:

```
Console.Write(""+data[44][0]);
output: 5
```

I hope you get what I mean. This is a very basic example of using arrays that I can't find how to use in C#. How could I do this? I have read Arrays Tutorial on msdn but I coldn't have even found how to create an array with first dimension dynamic (from 0 to infinite) and second static (from 0 to 6). Is there any simple solution how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<int, int[]>` if the key is unique (_"The first number is like a primary key"_)

Comment: Why don't you use `Dictionary<int,List<int>>`?

Comment: How would the output like look like if I used it? I mean this:    Console.Write(""+data[44][0]);

Comment: It sounds to me like you should probably actually create a new type to hold "An ID and a list of integers" - at which point you can have a `Dictionary<int, YourNewType>`. While you *can* just create a `Dictionary<int, int[]>` it's not as semantically clear (IMO) as creating a new type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> data = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();


data.Add(44, new int[]{5,8,0,0,2,5,9});
data.Add(99, new int[]{9,9,9,9,5,5,1});
data.Add(12, new int[]{0,0,9,5,1,7,1});
```

By using a dictionary you can get the desired effect with less complexity. It will enable you to create a unique key per array

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xfhwa508.aspx) if the key is unique what *"The first number is like a primary key"* suggests. You can use an `int[]` or `List<int>`(if it should be mutable) as value.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
var values = new[] { 5, 8, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9 };
dict.Add(44, values);
values = new[] { 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 1 };
dict.Add(99, values);
// ...
```

You access it via   key in a very efficient way:

```
Console.Write(dict[44][0]);  // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
data.Add(44, new List<int> { 5, 8, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9 });
data.Add(99, new List<int> { 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 5, 1 });
//....
```

and to utilize:

```
var id = 44;
var value1 = data[id][0];
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep your key as unique, then Dictionary is the best option for this as mentioned in the other answers, , if you want multiple keys per value then Lookup is the best option, [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)